More info on (undirected) virtual graphs (vertices and edges)
EDIT: OK, I think I seriously misexplained what I was looking to do. The "knight graph" below is just an EXAMPLE of finding shortest path, not the actual problem I'm trying to solve. My question: I had AI kludge up some A* graph code (apparently the link got removed), but I'm sure Julia has a library to deal with A* search which I should be using instead.
Consider an (infinite) undirected virtual graph where the vertices are integer lattice points (eg, [3,4]) and the edges are weight 1 "knight moves" from that lattice point. For example, the eight edges from [3,4] would be [4,6], [5,5], [5,3], [4,2], [2,2], [1,3], [1,5].
An A* search on the graph would find the shortest path between two lattice points using only "knight moves".
Since the graph is infinite, it has to be created "on the fly". For example, there would be a neighbors function that queries the neighbors of a given vertex and a weight function that queries the weight of a given edge. There could also be a heuristic function that helps A* algorithm find a path faster.
I've gotten Microsoft Copilot to create such a "virtual graph" for me in Julia, but I'd like to learn more about them. In particular, I'm guessing there are existing libraries for these types of graphs. However, both AI and search engines aren't super helpful because I think "virtual graph" is the wrong term
[I believe this question is very clearly about programming and not just math, and my definition of virtual graph is clear, so I am re-submitting it for review by other reviewers]
[this 2nd edit here just to meet bot requirements]

What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

There is no need for a search algorithm. You can always choose the best move in a greedily fashion. When the source is near the target you have some specific cases to deal with, but when they are far enough apart, you can always make the move that is most directed towards the target. No need for A*, no need for a graph.

I see no question in your post.

graduated from staging ground: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79107513

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_graph

What is the question?

After your edit you write "My question:", but what follows is not a question. It is just a statement.

This question is a trainwreck. I'm new to Stack -- is it OK to delete my question (and potentially repost it in very different format) or will that do bad things to other people?

As this question already got two answers, deleting the question would also delete those answers, which means the effort put in those posts is also lost. But yes, you could post a new question. I would advise to first follow the tour, and when you do make a new post, make sure it is practical, concrete, includes your efforts, a specific problem description, and make it a question.

For finding a knight-path on a grid you don't need to create a graph. You don't even have to use an A* search algorithm: you can greedily determine the path without having to consider alternatives.
Here are two functions that perform the job:

jumpFrom takes the coordinates of a square and finds a path to (0, 0). The input coordinates must not be negative, and the y-coordinate should not exceed the x-coordinate. The output is a sequence of moves each encoded as the position in the moves array.

shortestPath takes two coordinate pairs, for the two involved squares. It gets the relative distance between those two and calls the above function with it. Then it translates the resulting jumps to a sequence of coordinates.


moves = [[1,-2],[2,-1],[2,1],[1,2],[-1,2],[-2,1],[-2,-1],[-1,-2]]

function jumpsFrom(x::Int, y::Int)
    function add(jump::Int)
        x += moves[jump][1]
        y += moves[jump][2]
        push!(path, jump)
    end

    path = Array{Int}(undef, 0)
    x == 1 && y == 0 && add(3)
    if x >= 2 * y
        diff = (x - 2*y) % 4
        diff == 1 && add(8)
        diff == 2 && (add(5), add(8))
        diff == 3 && add(4)
        while x > 2 * y
            add(6)
        end
    else
        diff = (x + y) % 3
        diff == 1 && (add(8), add(6))
        diff == 2 && (add(1), add(6))
        x < 0 && add(3)
        while x < 2 * y
            add(8)
        end
    end
    while x != 0
        add(7)
    end
    return path
end

function shortestPath(a::Array{Int}, b::Array{Int})
    x, y = a
    dx = abs(b[1] - a[1])
    dy = abs(b[2] - a[2])
    path = [[x, y]]
    for jump in jumpsFrom(max(dx, dy), min(dx, dy))
        dx < dy && (jump = 1 + (14 - jump) % 8)
        a[2] < b[2] && (jump = 1 + (12 - jump) % 8)
        a[1] < b[1] && (jump = 9 - jump)
        push!(path, [x += moves[jump][1], y += moves[jump][2]])
    end
    return path
end

# demo call
println(shortestPath([10, 10],[12, 8]))


Limit the graph to a small tile and work out what the optimum move is to go in a certain direction:



Vector
Moves From (X,Y)
Distance/Moves




(+1,+0)
(X+2,Y+1) -> (X,Y+2) -> (X+1,Y)
0.33


(+1,+1)
(X+2,Y-1) -> (X+1,Y+1)
0.71


(+2,+0)
(X+1,Y+2) -> (X+2,Y)
1.00


(+2,+1)
(X+2,Y+1)
2.24


(+3,+0)
(X+2,Y+1) -> (X+4,Y+2) -> (X+3,Y)
1.00


(+3,+1)
(X+2,Y-1) -> (X+3,Y+1)
1.58


(+3,+3)
(X+2,Y+1) -> (X+3,Y+3)
2.12


(+4,+0)
(X+2,Y+1) -> (X+4,Y)
2.00


(+4,+3)
(X+1,Y+2) -> (X+2,Y+4) -> (X+4,Y+3)
1.67


(+5,+0)
(X+2,Y+1) -> (X+4,Y+2) -> (X+5,Y)
1.67


(+5,+5)
(X+2,Y+1) -> (X+4,Y+2) -> (X+6,Y+3) -> (X+5,Y+5)
1.77



You only need to find the optimum path in a 45° angle as you can reflect and rotate the moves to get the moves in the other octants.
This can be generate using the python code:
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from math import sqrt
from pprint import pprint


def generate_tile(num_moves):
    """Perform an iterative BFS to find the optimal moves for reachable co-ordinates."""
    tile = {(0,0):0}
    moves = [(2,1),(1,2),(-2,1),(-1,2),(2,-1),(1,-2),(-2,-1),(-1,-2)]
    paths = [(0,0,[])]
    for i in range(num_moves):
        new_paths = []
        for x,y,p in paths:
            for dx,dy in moves:
                if (x+dx,y+dy) not in tile:
                    tile[(x+dx,y+dy)] = p+[(dx,dy)]
                    new_paths.append((x+dx,y+dy,p+[(dx,dy)]))
        paths = new_paths
    return tile

tile = generate_tile(50)

bounds = 30
# Limit tile to single octant up to the bounds
for x, y in tuple(tile.keys()):
    if x <= 0 or x > bounds or y < 0 or y > x:
        del tile[(x, y)]

# Look for pairs of tiles that have the same number of moves as the optimum
# total combined move. If found then remove the combined move.
for ((x1,y1),p1), ((x2,y2),p2) in combinations_with_replacement(tuple(tile.items()), 2):
    if x1+x2>bounds or y1+y2>bounds:
        continue
    if (x1+x2,y1+y2) in tile and len(p1) + len(p2) == len(tile[(x1+x2,y1+y2)]):
        del tile[(x1+x2,y1+y2)]

distances = [
    (round(sqrt(x**2 + y**2)/len(p), 2), (x,y), p)
    for (x,y), p in tile.items()
]
distances.sort()
pprint(distances)

Then, if you are moving long distances, consider the angle (rounded to the nearest 22.5°, which uses the most efficient moves for each angle) and use the optimum move for that angle:



Angle (°)
Move




0°
(+4,+0)


22.5°
(+2,+1)


45°
(+3,+3)


67.5°
(+1,+2)


90°
(+0,+4)



Then to move larger distances, use multiples of the pattern to cover the long distance efficiently and then optimise (i.e. find the most efficient short-distance pattern) for the final short distance.

To move (+8,+0) then move (+4,+0) twice.
To move (+10,+0) then either (+4,+0) twice and (+2,+0) (in any order) or (+5,+0) twice.
To move (+253, +128) then move (+2,+1) 125 times and (+3,+3) once.
To move (+953, +872) then move (+3,+3) 262 times and (+2,+1) 81 times and (+5,+5) once.


There is no need for an A* algorithm or to use any weights or heuristics.

How do you know that your "small tile" is big enough?

@MattTimmermans If you are worried about it then double or triple the tile size and do an exhaustive search for more optimal solutions for that larger tile to look for sequences that are not composed of two-or-more of moves from the smaller tiles. The point is that you can break the problem down into a mathematical problem where you can repeat a pre-calculated sequence of optimal moves for the long-distance and only have to solve a short-distance final adjustment which you can pre-calcualte for a small tile as well - you do not need to use a path-finding algorithm.

My point is that you're skipping the most important and entertaining part -- finding the smallest tile size that is guarantees a shortest path.

@MattTimmermans Added some python code to generate the tile. The code tests out to 30x30 but the most efficient tile is contained in a 5x5 and the most efficient of those are the moves already listed in the long-distance section.
